# Conditional Expectation for a Joint PMF

Tags: conditional-expectation

Let (X; Y ) have joint mass function $P(k, n) = \frac {C*2^-k}{n}$ , for k = 1, 2,  and
n = 1, 2, , k, and suitable constant C. Compute $E(X|Y = y)$.

Its easy to calculate the $P(X,Y)$ but i am getting confused in calculating $P(Y)$ also what should be the value(range) of X. Can someone please provide some direction?

Answer (score 0):

The conditional distribution of $X$ is
$$p_{X|Y=y}(x) = \frac{p_{X,Y}(x,y)}{p_Y(y)}=\frac{P((X,y)=(x,y))}{P(Y=y)}.$$
You know the numerator already. The denominator can be found by partitioning the event $Y=y$ on the value of $X$:
$$P(Y=y)=\sum_{k=1}^2 P(Y=y \text{ and } X=x).$$
Finally, $E(X \mid Y=y)= \sum_{k=1}^2 x \cdot p_{X|Y=y}(x)$. The sum is over $k=1,2$ because according to the formula you gave, $X$ only takes on the values $1$ or $2$.

Comment: Thanks so much, i think i missed it in my question but K takes value from 1 to infinity but n takes value from 1 to K. I think the summation value will be from k=1 to infinity(denominator).  Is that correct and how do i compute it in this case?

Comment: can you please check my comment?

Comment: Yes, both sums will be from $k=1$ to $\infty$.